# How does Epiphany affect skills?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

With the new expansion Reaper of Souls, Monk has a new ability '[Epiphany](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/epiphany)'.

It's description is,

> Have an Epiphany, increasing your Spirit Regeneration per Second by 20
>   and enabling your melee attacks to instantly dash to your target for
>   15 seconds.

However I've noticed that it changes your skills. I use '[Lashing Tail Kick](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/lashing-tail-kick)' as my <kbd>1</kbd> and I've noticed that whilst Epiphany is running it essentially turns into Seven Sided Strike, and will hit enemies in the area.

What other changes are made to skills whilst Epiphany is active?

Or is this just Lashing Tail Kick's AoE being 'instantly dashed' to targets?

The effect can be seen in this video. Watch for the player popping Epiphany and notice the top boss gets struck with a glowing yellow shadow, similar to Seven Sided Strike.

Comment: Good question, I have noticed that Wave of Light is doing the same thing as Lashing Tail Kick.

Comment: I haven't noticed any changes, but I don't use any of the skills mentioned.

Comment: I've observed Cyclone Strike to be subject to the same "transformation". Only happens a fraction of the time, though.

Comment: Which rune are you using - does it matter?

Comment: Personally I'm using 'Scorpion Sting', but I doubt it has an effect on the animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this too. I am pretty sure that the extra monk attacks that look like Seven-Sided Strike are from Epiphany's Inner Fire rune.

> **Inner Fire:**
>
> Engulf yourself in flames, causing your attacks to assault enemies for
>   353% weapon damage as Fire.

It appears that spirit spenders can proc Inner Fire, and cause a Monk "afterimage" to attack any mob on screen, kind of like SSS. Alternatively, it could be Inner Fire proccing off Area Damage effects.

Here is a thread with additional discussion: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12285778532

**UPDATE:**

This thread has some more great information: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12427543033#7

> Procs on every spirit gen and spirit spender cast.
>
> Spirit gen - procs a line-nuke fireball dealing 353% weapon damage as
>   fire to all enemies in front of you (1s cooldown)
>
> Spirit spender -
>   procs a fire-image of your monkthat deals 353% weapon damage as fire
>   to a random target within ~50 yards (1s cooldown PER target)
>
> The way the spender version works --  when you attack with a
>   non-generator skill [...], several fire-images of your monk
>   will appear at random targets around you and hit it for 353% weapon
>   damage as fire.

Comment: Good link, but I do not think that it's due to the rune as Deadly Reach shoots fireballs when Epiphany is active.

Comment: The fireballs in the video are from a headgear modifier (@25seconds). The Azmodan fight shows it pretty well: the demons from offscreen take a quick hit and then the sword lightning zaps them. Other videos of Inner Fire show similar avatars jumping around.

Comment: Good shout @Wikwocket you were spot on. I did a test and it's all down to the rune! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVgllP2BfR0

Comment: Is anyone aware if epiphany has any hidden effects OTHER than the CC immunity?